# How to update dictionary values side by side?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary, I'm creating string with sorting values and adding the length of each field value at the beginning of dictionaries field value.
I have to update this values side by side and i have to hash it:

**But this string format is like that.**

```
25http://a1ff569e.ngrok.io/
2TR
17foootest@mail.com
3Adı
6Soyadı
1105316806562
3000
164355084355084358
212
42018
8OPU_TEST
192017-08-28 10:24:57
8Ürünkodu
15Ürün Açıklaması
9Ürün İsmi
3100
11
7Test123
15
218
8CCVISAMC
3TRY
```

How can i update this string values side by side like below ?

**I know i can print hashstring with end='' but this is not updating hashstring varabile's value like that just shown like that and **

25http://a1ff569e.ngrok.io/
2TR
17payutest@mail.com
3Adı
6Soyadı
1105316806562
3000
164355084355084358
212
42018
8PYKDMNSZ
192017-08-28 10:24:57
8Ürünkodu
15Ürün Açıklaması
9Ürün İsmi
3100
11
7Test123
15
218
8CCVISAMC
3TRY

```
# Importing required libraries for sample.
from datetime import datetime
import hmac
import hashlib
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

# Endpoint
url = "https://secure.payu.com.tr/order/alu/v3"
# PayU Merchant's Secret Key
secret = 'SECRET_KEY'
# Array Begin
array = {
    # PayU Merchant's Merchant ID
    'MERCHANT': "OPU_TEST",
    'ORDER_REF':  "Test123",
    'ORDER_DATE': datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
    'BACK_REF': "http://a1ff569e.ngrok.io/",
    'ORDER_PNAME[0]': "Ürün İsmi",
    'ORDER_PCODE[0]': "Ürünkodu",
    'ORDER_PINFO[0]': "Ürün Açıklaması",
    'ORDER_PRICE[0]': "100",
    'ORDER_VAT[0]': "18",
    'ORDER_QTY[0]': "1",
    'ORDER_SHIPPING': "5",
    'PRICES_CURRENCY': "TRY",
    'PAY_METHOD': "CCVISAMC",
    'SELECTED_INSTALLMENTS_NUMBER': "2",
    'CC_NUMBER': "4355084355084358",
    'EXP_MONTH': "12",
    'EXP_YEAR': "2018",
    'CC_CVV': "000",
    'BILL_FNAME': "Adı",
    'BILL_LNAME': "Soyadı",
    'BILL_PHONE': "05316806562",
    'BILL_EMAIL': "TEST@mail.com",
    'BILL_COUNTRYCODE': "TR",

}
# Sorting Array params
for k, v in sorted(array.items()):
# Adding the length of each field value at the beginning of field value
    hashstring = str(len(v)) + str(v)
    print(hashstring)
# Calculating ORDER_HASH
signature = hmac.new(secret.encode('utf-8'), hashstring.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.md5).hexdigest()
# Adding ORDER_HASH param to dictionary
array['ORDER_HASH'] = signature
print(signature)
print()

# Sending Request to Endpoint
request = Request(url, urlencode(array).encode())
json = urlopen(request).read().decode()
# Printing result
print(json)
```

Comment: Could you clarify a little? I'm having some difficulties trying to understand what you mean. What is the desired output that you are failing to achieve?

Comment: you can try `print(hashstring+" ", end="")`? thats going to get your desired output.

Comment: @N.Ivanov Ivanov yes i can get output with end="" but this is not update hashstring's value. I'm using below code for getting values from dictionary and sorting and getting lenght after that i have to hash that string but hash string created like in my question.

# Sorting Array params
for k, v in sorted(array.items()):
# Adding the length of each field value at the beginning of field value
    hashstring = str(len(v)) + str(v)
    print(hashstring+" ", end="")
# Calculating ORDER_HASH
signature = hmac.new(secret.encode('utf-8'), hashstring.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.md5).hexdigest()

Comment: what? what value do you want to update. Its quite difficult to understand what you want to achieve. Restructure your question, try to explain in clear english, and provide examples.

Comment: 1st I am refusing to read code from comments. 2nd this code is not in your question. 3rd the question DOES NOT MENTION anything to do with hashing. Please go and familiarise yourself on how to ask questions, and then post on SO. Thanks

Comment: @N.Ivanov sorry for that, i updated my question, could you please assist me ? :(

Comment: @Bit i updated my question, could you please assist me now ? i hope it's clear right know.

Comment: part of your question where you give an example is again unreadable (due to formatting), and also I still do not understand what do you want to achieve with this hashing. Therefore I cannot help you, and I believe it will be very difficult for anyone to help you with this level of detail. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but maybe it's works.
Please try and share results with us.

```
hashstring=print(hashstring+" ", end="")
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not fixed it

Comment: This is not an answer, but rather a comment (suggestion). Please go and read on how to create Good Answers. Thanks